# iOS - Why setting and displaying subviews in initWithNibName doesn't work?

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, xib

I have a simple xib file which its layout is:

[image]

Which the pale green UIView is referenced to an IBOutlet `view_content` in my UIViewController class. Then I did the following in `initWithNibName:bundle:` of my ViewController.m:

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nil];
if (self) {

    self.view_a = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    self.view_a.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [self.view_content addSubview:self.view_a];

    self.view_b = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 100, 100)];
    self.view_b.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view_content addSubview:self.view_b];

    self.view_c = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
    self.view_c.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view_content addSubview:self.view_c];

}
return self;
```

I expected there will be 3 small squares, each with different colors as declared in the code above, but they did not show up which the view is loaded and showed. But instead if I move the `addSubView:` calls into `viewDidLoad`, they are displayed as expected. I tried to test if `view_content` is nil in the if-segment and seems it is nil at that time. I don't understands why this is happening and how it works, isn't the view and its components are supposed to be loaded from the xib?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point `initWithNibName:...` is called, the view itself is not yet loaded. This is an optimization (lazy loading) that defers loading the view until it is actually needed. The view is actually loaded when `viewController.view` is first-time accessed, and that's when `viewDidLoad` is called.

Some people force the view controler to load its view by calling `[viewController view]` (or `[self view]` if it's within the view controller's class).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so is this means I should do all initializations and layouts of views related stuff in `viewDidLoad`, while I can still handle other variable initializations like BOOL in `initWithNibname:...`?

Comment: Sorry for late answer selection, thanks for you explanation, it makehs me understand the logic flow a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple. View is not loaded at that time when you are initializing the controller means initWithNibName. So best place is viewDidLoad where your all outlet has been assigned.